# ViewController and drawRect

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, drawrect

I have a UIViewController and I would like it to call drawRect so i can draw on the view but nothing happens.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
...code...
}

@end
```

and the implementation

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect {
draw a pony
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

But no pony gets drawn on the view when the app is run, what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UIViewController` don't have overridden message `drawRect`.
You should create custom class derived from `UIView` and override message `drawRect` there.

You can override message `(UIView *)view` for `UIViewController` and return own custom `UIView` or in Interface Builder change class from `UIView` to own class.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your `UIView`, not the `ViewController`, is one way of triggering and re-triggering your `drawRect` code, and you can send this message conditionally whenever you need to update the entire view.

You can call it within a custom `UIView` using

```
[self.setNeedsDisplay]
```

or from the View Controller by making the `UIView` a property of the controller and calling

```
[self.myView setNeedsDisplay]
```